# Get rotation data from matrix4

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix, rotation

I've been trawling the internet for this, and although I've found quite a lot all the solutions seem to be different so:

Please could someone give me a concise explanation of how to extract rotation data i.e. xyz from a matrix4 structure.

I understand that a matrix 4 is used to hold information on translation, scale and rotation but that's about as far as it goes. I'm coding for iOS and using GLKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all linear transformations are rotations; not all rotations can be expressed as Euler angles. Euler angle representations are also not unique — both trivially (e.g. angle a and angle a + 360 are the same) and not so (e.g. when axes are aliased). As Euler angle representations cover only a subset of the possible rotations, and rotations are only a subset of the possible matrices, conversion is not always possible.

If, however, you're talking only about that small subset of matrices that are rotations and can be expressed in Euler angles then [this is probably the paper for you](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~sbbh653/publications/euler.pdf). That starts from the observation that only one of the angles contributes to the third value in the first column, then uses elimination and trigonometric identities to find the rest. It discusses the many instances in which you need to manage multiple possible solutions to an angle in figuring out the next.

Comment: Thank you for putting me on the right path. Nice paper.